# Mapzen Turn-by-Turn routing in Leaflet Routing Machine with costings: "multimodal"

Tags: leaflet, routing, multimodal-network, mapzen

I wanto to setup a routing service for my leaflet map. The Route should route over pedestrian, train or bus. Mapzen Turn-by-Turn Routing is exactly providing this by using the option:

`costing: "multimodal":`

my fully code for routing looks like:

```
var control = L.Routing.control({
        waypoints: [
            L.latLng(52.410474, 12.972324),
            L.latLng(52.406777, 12.976380)
        ],
        routeWhileDragging: true,                   
        geocoder: L.Control.Geocoder.nominatim(),       
        router: L.Routing.mapzen('valhalla-nope', {costing:"multimodal"}),
                formatter: new L.Routing.mapzenFormatter()
    }).addTo(map);
```

I get a blank map when using mutlimodal. With auto, pedestrian, ... , its working fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Does it work better if you put in a time? Just browsing https://github.com/valhalla/demos/blob/gh-pages/routing/js/valhalla.js#L672

Comment: Okey just figured out it is not working in every area of the world. Just where the transit company offers their data. So apparently it works in NewYork, SanFrancisco and Rome ... too bad.

Comment: I guess it would be hard for multimodal to work without data for those public transport modes.